# Finding all solutions in prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

In prolog I'm trying to unify every valid pairing of needs with resources

```
needs([ece2090,1,m,13,16]).
needs([ece3520,1,tu,11,14]).
needs([ece4420,1,w,13,16]).

resources([joel, [ece2090,ece2010,ece3520,ece4420],[[m,13,16]]]).
resources([sam, [ece2010,ece4420],[]]).
resources([pete, [ece3520],[[w,13,16]]]).
```

using this formula

```
make_bid([Class,Sect,Day,Ts,Te],[Name,Cap,Unavail],[Class,Sect,Day,Ts,Te,Name,_]) :-
no_conflict_all_unavailable(Day,Ts,Te,Unavail),
course_capable(Class,Cap),
writef('%w %w %w\n',[Class,Sect,Name]),
fail.
```

and running this test.

```
test(Listing) :- needs(N), resources(R), make_bid(N,R,Listing).
```

The point of this part of the program is to pair every class with a teacher that both has the qualifications to teach the class and is not unavailable during that time. It's supposed to give a list.

```
?- test(Listing).
ece3520 1 joel
ece3520 1 pete
ece4420 1 joel
ece4420 1 sam
false.
```

When run, the above is generated. This is correct, but it's in a format that's useless to me, since I need it to be a variable of its own to do further computations. Then the solution is to use bagof or findall, right?

So I remove the fail clause from the main part of the program and then change the test to this

```
test(Bag) :- needs(N), resources(R), bagof(Listing,make_bid(N,R,Listing),Bag).
```

but it generates this

```
ece3520 1 joel
Bag = [[ece3520, 1, tu, 11, 14, joel, _G4310]]
```

If you look closely you'll see that there's no period at the end as well as a lack of a true/false statement. This would lead one to believe it is infinitely looping. This isn't the case however, as the Bag matrix is fully formed and I can simply type "." to end the program (instead of, you know, aborting it).

It only generates the first valid solution. Why is this happening?

Comment: Don't you have to make a teacher unavailable if he gives one class? I'd go with `bagof(N, needs(N), Needs)` and then recourse, since the available times change. Can't help you with your question, though.

Comment: Oh, actually I do know that: one of your predicates is generating a open branch, that hasn't been considered yet. The smallest knowledge base I could come up as a simple case is this: `a. a:-fail.`. if you query `?- a.` You'll get first `true` and after asking for more, `false`. Some Prolog systems replace `true` with a variable binding, if there is one. So to get closer to your case, take `a(1). a(_):-fail` and query `?- a(A)`.

Comment: try findall instead of bagof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've structured your `test` predicate so that `bagof/3` is called for every instance combination of `needs(N)` and `resources(R)` and so it collects each result of `make_bid` in it's own `bagof/3` result:

```
ece3520 1 joel
Bag = [[ece3520, 1, tu, 11, 14, joel, _G4310]]
```

The first line is the `write` that is in `make_bid` predicate. The second line is the `Bag` result for the single query to `make_bid` for one pair of `needs`/`resources`. The last argument in the list, `_G4310`, occurs because your predicate uses `_` and it's anonymous (never used/instantiated).

Your current `make_bid` is designed to write the results in a loop rather than instantiate them in multiple backtracks. So that could be changed to:

```
make_bid([Class, Sect, Day, Ts, Te], [Name, Cap, Unavail], [Class, Sect, Day, Ts, Te, Name, _]) :-
    no_conflict_all_unavailable(Day, Ts, Te, Unavail),
    course_capable(Class, Cap).
```

(NOTE: I'm not sure why you have `_` at the end of the 3rd list argument. What does it represent?)

If you want to collect the whole result in one list, then you canb use `findall/3`:

```
findall([Class, Sect, Name], (needs(N), resources(R), make_bid(N, R, [Class, Sect, _, _, _, Name, _]), Listings).
```

This will collect a list of elements that look like, `[Class, Sect, Name]`.  You could use `bagof/3` here, but you'd need an existential quantifier for the variables in the `make_bid/3` call that you don't want to bind.

If you wanted the entire `Listing` list, then:

```
findall(L, (needs(N), resources(R), make_bid(N, R, L)), Listings).
```

But each element of `Listings` will be a list whose last element is an anonymous variable, since that's how `make_bid/3` is structured.

Comment: I'm having another problem. First off, thank you, this has been a lot of help. I got the matrix I wanted. Problem is, I no longer want a matrix. I would like the program to produce a bids variable structured the same as needs and resources, and then I can go from there. Do you know how to do that? I feel like it's a simple edit but I don't know where to find that information.

As to your question of why the _ was in there, this is a code snippet and I was experimenting. The variable just so happened to be junk at the moment.

Comment: @PowerOfKaishin yes, it's a straightforward change. Exactly what do you want the terms to look like?

Comment: erm, sorry to be so jumpy, but i decided to scrap that idea, at least for now. I went back to the drawing boards because matrices are the best way to do operations in prolog but they pretty much make backtracking impossible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289344/prolog-finding-all-solutions