# Prolog how to use if / else in this way?

Tags: if-statement, prolog

In Prolog, i want to use an if-else statement in the following way:

```
lecture(spanish,monday,at8).
lecture(french,monday,at8).
lecture(english,monday,at10).
lecture(german,tuesday,at8).

generatePossibleSchedulesWithTwoLectures(LectureA,LectureB):-
     lecture(LectureA,A,X),
     lecture(LectureB,B,Y),
     %If A of LectureA is equal to B of lectureB -> times must be un-equal
     % How to do implement the requirement of the line above here?
```

As a result, the function should generate schedules with two lectures which are not in the same time slot.

Comment: In Prolog, `If-Then-Else` is expressed with `( A -> B ; C)`. I don't understand the rest of your requirements but that should be everything you need to make it work yourself.

Comment: Yes, ive read about that. However, that will output the following:
LectureA = spanish,
LectureB = english ;
LectureA = french,
LectureB = english ;
LectureA = english,
LectureB = spanish ;
LectureA = english,
LectureB = french ;
false.

It misses a lot of possible solutions. For example, the second solution should be spanish + german.

Comment: What do you mean with "that". Edit your question to show your approach/code.

Answer (score 2):

You started by assuming, *i want to use an if-else statement in the following way*, but the logic of your problem doesn't describe an if-then-else condition. An `if-then-else` isn't the construct you want to achieve your goal of:

> Generate schedules with two lectures which are not in the same time slot

Also, the Prolog `if-then-else` construct `A -> B ; C` removes the choice point you are after. For some detail on this, see the answer to, [What's the meaning of Prolog operator '->'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051798/whats-the-meaning-of-prolog-operator/29052243#29052629)

What you really want is to say:

*A schedule two lectures `A` & `B` is valid **if** `Day1` and `Time1` are a time slot for `A`, **and** `Day2` and `Time2` are a time slot for `B`, **and** time slots `Day1-Time1` and `Day2-Time2` are different.*

If fact, to avoid duplicates and to keep the schedule in chronological order, we can enforce that the "first" time slot is earlier than the second. This translates to:

```
generate_possible_schedules_with_two_lectures(LectureA, LectureB):-
    lecture(LectureA, Day1, Time1),
    lecture(LectureB, Day2, Time2),
    dif(LectureA, LectureB),   % don't schedule the same class
    Day1-Time1 @< Day2-Time2   % timeslots in order, and different
```

We simplify the time slot comparison by forming a term `A-B` with the day and time. You could do the longer comparison, comparing the day and tie individually, replacing `Day1-Time1 @< Day2-Time2` with `(Day1 @< Day2 ; Day1 == Day2, Time1 @< Time2)`. In either case, you get the following results with your data:

```
?- generate_possible_schedules_with_two_lectures(A, B).
A = spanish,
B = german ;
A = french,
B = german ;
A = english,
B = spanish ;
A = english,
B = french ;
A = english,
B = german ;
false.
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. However, your solution does not allow to check if to given lectures would fit together , for example with calling generate_possible_schedules_with_two_lectures(german, spanish). I think it does not work because you excluded the dublicates, right?

Comment: @user2945914 yes good catch. Perhaps you could try to modify what I've done to handle that. I'm away from home at the moment so I can't easily access.

Comment: @user2945914 The easy thing to do is use `dif/2` again for the `date-time` instead of `@<`, which may yield duplicates.

Comment: Okay, tank you. Would it be complicated to do this task with a lot of more defined lectures and having result schedules with 5 instead of 2 lectures per result? Would I have to check every time/day of a lecture agains all others manually or is there a cool Prolog magic for that?

Comment: @user2945914 as long as you use the same day/time format for all your data, and you want the same rules, it should work no matter how much data you have.

Comment: @user2945914 if you find my answer acceptable, perhaps you could click the "Accept" for the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. I can only vote up your answher when I have 15 reputations.

Comment: @user2945914 yes that is true for up vote. But you can accept the answer. There's a separate button for that. It's a check mark.

Comment: All in all, I have to generate schedules with  lectures instead of 2. Will i have to check then Day1-Time1 @< Day2-Time2, Day1-Time1 @< Day3-Time3, Day1-Time1 @< Day4-Time4, Day1-Time1 @< Day5-Time5, Day2-Time2 @< Day3-Time3, Day2-Time2 @< Day4-Time4......etc... manually or is there a cool prolog magic for that?

Comment: @user2945914 I'd use a list for the lectures and ensure that the list of potential time slots don't have overlap. You wouldn't literally say, `Day1-Time1`, `Day2-Time2`, etc, since you want an arbitrary number of them. Thus, the use of a list. You would need a predicate that checked that the list had no overlaps. Check, for example, [this question and solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289344/prolog-finding-all-solutions/28298843#28298843).